# Get function called by inputbox

Tags: javascript, web-applications, reverse-engineering

I need to overload the function that is called by a input when the enter button is pressed in order to execute my code and then decide if call the function that the inputbox come with or not.

The WebApp is not mine and the js come minimized.

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: All depends on the code. Hard to know without seeing some code.

Comment: @epascarello there is no code, how I wrote the webapp is not mine this is why I would understand if there is some way to get some ref to the function tha is already binded

Comment: The issue is it depends on the code....There is no way to know what the click handler is doing.

Comment: ok then this is the answer :-)

Comment: Maybe this link https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events#view_event_listeners_registered_on_objects
can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer by myself:
***Monitor Events*** of Chrome DevTools Command Line API offers various ways to observe and inspect event listeners. JavaScript plays a central role in interactive pages, and the browser provides you some useful tools to debug events and event handlers.

For more info: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events#view_event_listeners_registered_on_objects